# CodeIgniter doesn't unset session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i can't logout in my application with codeigniter

my code looks like this:

```
public function logout() 
{
   $sess = $this->CI->session->all_userdata();
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata($sess["session_id"]);
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata($sess["ip_address"]);
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata($sess["user_agent"]);
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata($sess["last_activity"]);
   $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
   return true;
}
```

I'm calling this function on my `login` controller

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->Helper("password");
  $this->auth->logout();
  var_dump($this->auth->is_loggedin());
}
```

var_dump is always `bool(true)`. How I can solve the problem?

Comment: what library  are you using for your authentication in codeigniter ? and also if possible can you post the code for `is_loggedin` function

Comment: what is `$this->auth->is_loggedin()`

Comment: @anurupr i use "aauth" and you can find the function here: https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth/blob/master/application/libraries/Aauth.php#L140

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9019204/839456

Comment: i modified the function "logout" with my function above in my code. isn't that the right code?

Comment: it doesn't look wrong. but probably its not getting unset due to various reasons. were you able to run it and check?

Comment: i run it on /index.php/login in the __construct() function

Comment: i see. did you modify the logout function and run it?

Comment: @anurupr yes but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that even though you have called `sess_destroy` the session exist for the rest of the current page build.  What happens if you try this?

```
public function logout() 
{
   //No need to unset individual items just call sess_destroy
   $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
   return true;
}
```

and then after you call the `logout` function do a redirect

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->Helper("password");
  $this->auth->logout();
  redirect('/test/', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i logout the user on /login/logout and the redirect is on /login/ and the sessions is no destroyed. When redirect to /test/ the session is destroyed.

Comment: on "/login" CodeIgniter creates a new cookie wiht the session details

Comment: yes but when i visit /login after logout it creates a new session and i'm logged in

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the values of your session data, try using the keys themselves. Like this:

```
public function logout() 
{
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata("session_id");
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata("ip_address");
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata("user_agent");
   $this->CI->session->unset_userdata("last_activity");
   $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
   return true;
}
```