# Authentication redirection in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter framework. I am trying to build a authentication system.

Authentication is working fine. My problem is that after successfully logging, when I click the back button in the browser it is directed to login page again. I want to redirect it to the home page itself. i want to reload the home page not the index page(index page is the login page, after successful login goes to home page)

How can I do it

Comment: With out some code bit hard to help you. You can re edit your question by clicking on edit button below tags

Answer (score 0):

In your login page check that login session is started or not, if it is started than redirect to home page :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header('Location:http://localhost/projectname/home');   
}
```

If you have any confusion please let me inform.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

on the home page controller check whether the session exists or not. if it exists then redirect to home page otherwise login page.

In your **home_model.php** do something like below:

```
<?php

class Home_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->check_session();
    }

    function check_session()
    {
        $session_login = $this->session->userdata("MYLOGIN");
        if($session_login == '')
        {
            redirect('home');
        }
        if($session_login == 1 && $session_login == TRUE)
        {
            redirect('home/dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Load **home_model** in **home** controller.

Comment: i'm using webservices dont have model

Comment: then put this into controller.

Comment: you are not following MVC structure, if you are using CI framework @Sonali

Comment: i'm following the MVC structure but data is coming from other server thats why m using webservices

Comment: i've tried but not when i echo the session variable on login page it is still active in browser but destroyed from server side.

Comment: *data is coming from other server* - means?

Comment: data is coming through webservices from db

Comment: i got it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019031/codeigniter-sess-destroy-not-working-properly-what-m-i-doing-wrong